# Build a image from multiple images

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

I have multiple images (more than 1000 / 288*288) with their respective coordinates (X,Y).
All pictures put together should displayed a unique picture. However some picture are missing.

Would it be possible to create a blank picture (via an array taken max(Y) and max(X)) and put each picture in the appropriate place?

Thanks